# how to emulate Sony Xperia ZL (model c6506) in eclipse?

Tags: android, voip, sony

I built a voip app and a stranger said the audio isn't playing on the Sony Xperia ZL (model c6506).  The microphone works though.  So taht means the Sony Xperia ZL user can speak and the other party can listen, but the Sony Xperia ZL user can't hear what the other party is saying.

I don't see an AVD option for a c6506 emulator/simulator.  Is there anyway to debug for that specific model WITHOUT actually acquiring the phone?  If not, then does anyone know if there's something specific about the C6506 that may cause the audio to not work?

My voip app is working fine for the S2, S3, S4, Note 1, Note 2, Sony Xperia Z, HTC Amaze, HTC One, Nexus 4 and Galaxy Nexus.   Not sure what is so special about the C6506?

Other details:
I'm using Linphone Core as the Sip library.  I'm using asterisk 1.8 as the server.  Everything else about my app is very straightforward.  It's simply dial the userid of the person you'd like to call, then you can hang up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is that you don't want to purchase a ZL to actually test on we do have a loaner program where you can borrow a ZL to debug on.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/borrow-a-phone/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to debug for that specific model WITHOUT actually acquiring the phone?

Probably not. Even if SONY published dedicated emulator images -- and I am not aware that they do -- the emulator cannot emulate that devices audio chipset, or WiFi/mobile data characteristics, etc. You are welcome to create an AVD with the same Android OS level that is used on that device and see if you can reproduce the problem, though since the emulator doesn't emulate a microphone (last I checked), even that may not work especially well.